# Extract key-value pairs from a JSON file with custom output formatting

Tags: json, awk, sed, grep, jq

I want to grep a combination of two words from a huge log file, the words are scattered and not in any particular order.

Sample log:

```
    {"1a":"2017-01-28 00:00:00","2a":"sample","a":"12345","b":"2017-02-06","c":"2017-02-06T17:51:02.454-08:00","d":"Mozilla/5.0
    ; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008070208 Firefox/3.0.1","e":"2017-02-06 
    ","f":"03","g":"example","h":"logA","i":"IFX","j":"a85","k":"12345678"},
{"1a":"2017-01-28 00:00:11","2a":"sample","a":"12345","b":"2017-02-06","c":"2017-02-06T17:51:02.454-08:00","d":"Mozilla/5.0
    ; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008070208 Firefox/3.0.1","e":"2017-02-06 
    ","f":"03","g":"example","h":"logB","i":"IFX","j":"a85","k":"12345678"}
```

In this file, I want to grep `"1a":"<value>"` and `"h":"<value of logA or logB>"` which there should not be any duplicates.

Expected Output:

```
"1a":"2017-01-28 00:00:00" "h":"logA"
"1a":"2017-01-28 00:00:11" "h":"logB"
```

I tried using egrep this way but it gives the entire line :

```
egrep -oE '1a\|"h"' but this does not give the required output.

awk /pattern1/ && /pattern2/ filename #no use
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: `DO NOT` use text/stream processors/editors for parsing `JSON`, use a proper parser like `jq`

Comment: Format your text input in proper `JSON` format and install `jq`

Comment: Also, regular expressions aren't designed patterns. Tag removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of standard utilities, consider use of the very flexible **[`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) JSON CLI**, which:

- simplifies the solution
- makes it robust
- allows it to be generalized.

```
echo '
[
  { "1a":"2017-01-28 00:00:00", "2a":"sample", "h":"logA", "i":"IFX" }, 
  { "1a":"2017-01-28 00:00:11", "2a":"sample", "h":"logB", "i":"IFX" }
]' |
  jq -r --argjson keys '[ "1a", "h" ]' '
    .[] | "\"\($keys[0])\": \"\(.[$keys[0]])\" \"\($keys[1])\": \"\(.[$keys[1]])\""
  '
```

<sup>To be self-contained, the command provides literal input via the pipeline and is formatted for readability.

To instead pass a *file* to the `jq` command, simply specify its path after the script's closing `'`

(`jq -r ... '...' file.json`)</sup>

yields:

```
"1a": "2017-01-28 00:00:00" "h": "logA"
"1a": "2017-01-28 00:00:11" "h": "logB"
```

- `--argjson keys '[ "1a", "h" ]'` defines variable `$keys` as a JSON-formatted array of the names of the keys (properties) to extract.
- `.[]` enumerates all elements of the input array - the individual objects - and `$keys[<n>]` and `.[$keys[<n>]]` expand to the property name with index `<n>` and the *value* for that property name, respectively (note the `.[...]` accessor).
- Most of the effort is spent on output formatting: Embedded `"` chars. must be escaped as `\"`, and embedded variable references must be enclosed in `\(...)` - although using `+` with separate tokens to build a string is also an option.

#### Generalizing the solution

The above command isn't easily generalized to an arbitrary number of key-value pairs to output per line, because the because the array indices (`0` and `1`) are *explicitly* specified.

Inspired by [peak's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42419332/45375), which shows a simple example of defining a helper *function* in `jq`, the following variant uses a combination of built-in functions and a custom function to **accept an *arbitrary* number of keys to extract**:

```
echo '
[
  { "1a":"2017-01-28 00:00:00", "2a":"sample", "h":"logA", "i":"IFX" },
  { "1a":"2017-01-28 00:00:11", "2a":"sample", "h":"logB", "i":"IFX" }
]
' |
  jq -r --argjson keys '[ "1a", "h", "i"  ]' '
    def printKv($k; $v): "\"\($k)\": \"\($v)\"";
    .[] | . as $o | 
      reduce $keys[] as $k (""; . + if .=="" then "" else " " end + printKv($k; $o[$k]))
  '
```

yields (3 key-value pairs per line, because 3 keys were passed):

```
"1a": "2017-01-28 00:00:00" "h": "logA" "i": "IFX"
"1a": "2017-01-28 00:00:11" "h": "logB" "i": "IFX"
```

The built-in `reduce` function is used to build up the target string by iterating over the key-value pairs and creating the string representation for each with the help of custom function `printKv`.

---

Following another suggestion by [peak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/997358/peak) , here's **a simpler, more `jq`-like alternative that yields the same output**:

```
echo '
[
  { "1a":"2017-01-28 00:00:00", "2a":"sample", "h":"logA", "i":"IFX" },
  { "1a":"2017-01-28 00:00:11", "2a":"sample", "h":"logB", "i":"IFX" }
]
' |
  jq -r --argjson keys '[ "1a", "h", "i"  ]' '
    def printKv($k): "\"\($k)\": \"\(.[$k])\"";
    .[] | [ $keys[] as $k | printKv($k) ] | join(" ")
  '
```

- `printKv()` now takes only a single parameter - the *key* `$k` - and relies on the pipeline input - still containing the input object - to extract the associated *value* - `.[$k]`
- Enclosing `$keys[] as $k | printKv($k)` in `[ ... ]` passes the output from the *multiple* `printKv` calls as a *single array* through the pipeline.
- This then allows the built-in `join` function to join the array elements with spaces to form a single output line.

Comment: thanks @mklement0, appreciate the long explanations for the answers :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a tweak of @mklement0's excellent answer. By defining a "print-me" function, the tweak minimizes the annoyance of having to escape double-quotation marks:

```
def q: "\"\(tostring)\"";

.[] | "\($keys[0]|q): \(.[$keys[0]]|q) \($keys[1]|q): \(.[$keys[1]]|q)"
```

Or if you prefer:

```
def printKV($k): "\"\($k)\": \"\(.[$k])\""; 

.[] | printKV($keys[0]) + " " + printKV($keys[1])
```

#### Generalized solution

With `printKV/1` as defined immediately above, and assuming $keys is defined on the command line (or by other means) as an array of strings:

```
def printKeyValues(keys):
  [keys[] as $key | printKV($key)] | join(" ");

.[] | printKeyValues($keys)
```

Comment: how can we pass the above jq command with a file, only generating unique values for these keys?

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F, -v RS={ 'NR>1 {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
                         {if($i~/"1a":/) printf "%s", $i OFS
                          if($i~/"h":"log(A|B)"/) printf "%s\n", $i}}' file


"1a":"2017-01-28 00:00:00" "h":"logA"
"1a":"2017-01-28 00:00:11" "h":"logB"
```

of course better to use json aware tools.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how can I also print the entire json string after the specified keys(here 1a and h), sample output like - `"1a":"2017-01-28 00:00:00" "h":"logA" {"1a":"2017-01-28 00:00:00","2a":"sample","a":"12345","b":"2017-02-06","c":"20‌​17-02-06T17:51:02.45‌​4-08:00","d":"Mozill‌​a/5.0 ; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008070208 Firefox/3.0.1","e":"2017-02-06 ","f":"03","g":"example","h":"logA","i":"IFX","j":"a85","k":‌​"12345678"}`

Answer (score 0):

**Input**

```
$ cat log
    {"1a":"2017-01-28 00:00:00","2a":"sample","a":"12345","b":"2017-02-06","c":"2017-02-06T17:51:02.454-08:00","d":"Mozilla/5.0
    ; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008070208 Firefox/3.0.1","e":"2017-02-06 
    ","f":"03","g":"example","h":"logA","i":"IFX","j":"a85","k":"12345678"},
{"1a":"2017-01-28 00:00:11","2a":"sample","a":"12345","b":"2017-02-06","c":"2017-02-06T17:51:02.454-08:00","d":"Mozilla/5.0
    ; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008070208 Firefox/3.0.1","e":"2017-02-06 
    ","f":"03","g":"example","h":"logB","i":"IFX","j":"a85","k":"12345678"}
```

**Output**

```
$ awk -F, -v RS='[{}]' '{s=""; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/^"(1a|h)":/)s=(s?s OFS:"") $i; if(s)print s}'  log 
"1a":"2017-01-28 00:00:00" "h":"logA"
"1a":"2017-01-28 00:00:11" "h":"logB"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how can I also print the entire json string after the specified keys(here 1a and h), sample output like - `"1a":"2017-01-28 00:00:00" "h":"logA" {"1a":"2017-01-28 00:00:00","2a":"sample","a":"12345","b":"2017-02-06","c":"2017-02-06T17:51:02.454-08:00","d":"Mozilla/5.0
    ; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008070208 Firefox/3.0.1","e":"2017-02-06 
    ","f":"03","g":"example","h":"logA","i":"IFX","j":"a85","k":"12345678"} `

Comment: @user2340345: you just need `print s,$0` like this `awk -F, -v RS='[{}]' '{s=""; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/^"(1a|h)":/)s=(s?s OFS:"") $i; if(s)print s,$0}'  log`

Comment: Thanks for $0 hint, that helped me leverage a mix of your answer and @karafka answer.